# SAS SEQ+1 in Teradata

Tags: sql, sas, teradata, row-number, seq

I am converting following code in SAS to Teradata

```
DATA T_SEQ;
SET Macro_SEQ;
SEQ+1;
by Sec_key;
IF FIRST.Sec_key then SEQ=1;
```

My teradata script is

```
select *, Row_Number() over (partition by Sec_key Order by SEC_key) as SEQ
from T_SEQ
```

Problem is teradata script is not giving me the same ouput like SAS Script and I am getting different sequence number in teradata output as compare to SAS Script.

```
Basically I need this type of SEQ
---------  -------------------- ---------------  
Australia            1421810.92    1  
Canada               2604540.71    1  
Canada               1453719.46    2  
Central              3189418.36    1  
France               3121616.32    1
```

Comment: Try without `PARTITION BY Sec_key`

Comment: Tried but not getting the desired output.

Comment: Ok, what is the desired output? Can you show an example?

Comment: Updated in my Main Question. Teradata  SEQUENCE number of SEC_Key is different from SAS Sequence number of SEC_Key. It should be same likes as SAS Seq number.

Comment: SAS assigns the sequence simply based on the order of rows in the input file.Teradata assigns the row number based on ORDER BY, if you order by SEC_key it's a random order.  Check if there's a column which can be used for sorting the row_number to match SAS: `(partition by Sec_key Order by ???)`